# Почему не передаются данные через QTcpSocket в Qt?

Tags: tcp-ip, qt, c++, сокет

У меня есть два простых приложения, которые я практически полностью переписал из учебника Макса Шлее по Qt 4.5
Клиент и сервер. Задача достаточно тривиальная, запускается сервер и слушает 2013 порт, запускается клиент и устанавливает соединение используя QTcpSocket, а дальше клиент может отсылать текстовые сообщения, которые будут приниматься сервером и выводиться в QTextEdit, клиент в свою очередь принимает ответы сервера и точно так же их выводит.
Проблема в том, что соединение устанавливается, но вывода сообщений я добиться не могу.

Qt Creator 2.7.0 
Основан на Qt 5.0.2 (32-х битной)
Компилятор MinGW 32-х битная версия
ОС Windows 7 64-х битная версия

**client.cpp**

```
void Widget::slotSendToServer()
{
    QByteArray arrBlock;
    QDataStream serverSendStream(&arrBlock, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    serverSendStream << quint16(0) << QTime::currentTime()
                     << messageLineEdit->text();

    serverSendStream.device()->seek(0);
    serverSendStream << quint16(arrBlock.size() - sizeof(quint16));

    tcpSocket->write(arrBlock);
    messageLineEdit->clear();
}
```

**server.cpp**

```
void Widget::slotReadClient()
{
    QTcpSocket *tcpSocket = (QTcpSocket*)sender();
    QDataStream clientReadStream(tcpSocket);
    while(true)
    {
        if (!next_block_size)
        {
            if (tcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < sizeof(quint16))
            {
                break;
            }
            clientReadStream >> next_block_size;
        }

        if (tcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < next_block_size)
        {
            break;
        }
        QTime   time;
        QString str;
        clientReadStream >> time >> str;

        QString strMessage =
                time.toString() + " " + "Client has sent - " + str;
        logTextEdit->append(strMessage);

        next_block_size = 0;

        sendToClient(tcpSocket,
                     "Server Response: Received \"" + str + "\"");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На случай если кому-то понадобится, нужно каждый раз инициализировать

```
next_block_size = 0
```

перед чтением из потока, даже в первый раз.

Answer (score -1):

Для ответа желательно все ваши файлы (`pro, cpp, h`), используемая платформа, название и версия компилятора.

Ну, и сюда можно заглянуть:

- [QTcpSocket Class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qtcpsocket.html)
- [Клиент-серверный чат, используя сокеты Qt/C++](http://habrahabr.ru/post/131585/)

Comment: Я обновил вопрос.
За статьи спасибо, почитаю.

Comment: > qmake client.pro
WARNING: Failure to find: main.cpp
WARNING: Failure to find: widget.cpp
WARNING: Failure to find: widget.h

> qmake server.pro
WARNING: Failure to find: main.cpp
WARNING: Failure to find: widget.cpp
WARNING: Failure to find: widget.h

А это как может быть?
  server.h
  #ifndef WIDGET_H
  #define WIDGET_H

Comment: Названия файлов не server.h, client.h тд, я назвал их так для ясности. На самом деле они все называются именем класса widget.h, widget.cpp и тд. Я думал, что это ясно из .pro файлов.